# What is a hadith "Daif-in-Chain" mean?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

If a hadith is graded Daif in chain does it mean that its content (matn) is Sahih authentic but the chain is weak but can it still be used as evidence?

Here is a example:

‘Amir Al Sha’bi said “The Prophet (ﷺ) had a special portion in the booty called safi. This would be a slave if he desired or a slave girl if he desired or a horse if he desired. He would choose it before taking out the fifth.”

Grade   : Da'if in chain (Al-Albani)

https://sunnah.com/abudawud/20/64